# How to call the nft mint by the contract?

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to call the mint function:

```
#[payable]
    pub fn buy_nft(&mut self, token_id: String) {
             self.tokens.mint(
                  token_id,
                  new_owner_id,
                  Some(token_metadata),
        )
}
```

But the predecessor needs to by owner_id, my owner_id is the contract id on which contract is deployed.
[Link](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/near-contract-standards/src/non_fungible_token/core/core_impl.rs#L347)

```
assert_eq!(env::predecessor_account_id(), self.owner_id, "Unauthorized");
```

When I call this function by say charlie, it gives Uauthorized error:

```
call!(
    charlie,
    contract.buy_nft("123".to_owned()),
    deposit = to_yocto("10")
).assert_success();
```

Error:

```
Smart contract panicked: panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
      left: `"charlie"`,
     right: `"contractname"`: Unauthorized'
```

How can I call self.token_mint by the contract, through charlie?

Comment: This seems like an issue with standard implementation. Such kind of permissioning should not be enforce inside the implementation, but should be enforced by the usage code.

Comment: Filled as an issue here: https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/issues/542

Meantime, you will need to copy the code from `mint` method customize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the answer is to copy the `mint` function from the standard implementation and customize as you see fit.

The better interface will be coming in the future updates.